# NSDateFormatter or NSDateComponents return the same number for different dates

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I did build a custom calendar and when I go through the week changing the day number for day, I see strange situation when date is 26, but NSDateFormatter and NSDateComponents return 27, the same is for 27 = 27, you can see a log from. In another case 31 is 30, and the 1 is 31

Does anybody had something like that?

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in weekViews) {
    UILabel *dayName = dict[@"dayName"];
    UILabel *dayNumber = dict[@"dayNumber"];

    components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:tempDate];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    formatter.dateFormat = @"dd";

    //TODO:Remove NSLog
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", [formatter stringFromDate:tempDate], tempDate);

    dayName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", weekDaySymbols[index++]];
    dayNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", components.day];

    tempDate = [tempDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400];
}
```

2013-10-22 01:06:25.812 Care[539:70b] 27 = 2013-10-26 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:06:25.813 Care[539:70b] 27 = 2013-10-27 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:06:25.813 Care[539:70b] 28 = 2013-10-28 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:06:25.814 Care[539:70b] 29 = 2013-10-29 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:06:25.814 Care[539:70b] 30 = 2013-10-30 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:06:25.815 Care[539:70b] 31 = 2013-10-31 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:06:25.816 Care[539:70b] 01 = 2013-11-01 21:00:00 +0000

Another examples for that code:

2013-10-22 01:14:12.456 Care[539:70b] 22 = 2014-03-22 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:14:12.456 Care[539:70b] 23 = 2014-03-23 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:14:12.457 Care[539:70b] 24 = 2014-03-24 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:14:12.457 Care[539:70b] 25 = 2014-03-25 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:14:12.458 Care[539:70b] 26 = 2014-03-26 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:14:12.458 Care[539:70b] 27 = 2014-03-27 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:14:12.459 Care[539:70b] 28 = 2014-03-28 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:12:34.942 Care[539:70b] 29 = 2014-03-29 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:12:34.943 Care[539:70b] 31 = 2014-03-30 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:12:34.943 Care[539:70b] 01 = 2014-03-31 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:12:34.944 Care[539:70b] 02 = 2014-04-01 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:12:34.944 Care[539:70b] 03 = 2014-04-02 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:12:34.945 Care[539:70b] 04 = 2014-04-03 21:00:00 +0000

2013-10-22 01:12:34.945 Care[539:70b] 05 = 2014-04-04 21:00:00 +0000

I did break my brain :)

Comment: (And when does daylight savings time end/begin where you are?)

Comment: (In case you don't know, "Summer Time" in the Ukraine ends the last Sunday in October and begins again the last Sunday in March.)

Comment: It seems like it is a good point. But, how I have to setup daylight?

Comment: Do I have to increment date on 1 hour manually to have it works, because adding of current local to NSDateFormat or NSDateComponents didn't make any change to result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main thing to understand is that NSLog will *always* dump an NSDate in UTC timezone.  Also, to increment date by one day you should use NSCalendar dateByAddingComponents vs simply adding 24 hours to NSDate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it was related to DST (daylight saving time). I just had replaced using of NSDateFormat for incrementing of day to NSDateComponent.

```
NSDate *tempDate = currentDate;

for (NSDictionary *dict in weekViews) {
    UILabel *dayName = dict[@"dayName"];
    UILabel *dayNumber = dict[@"dayNumber"];

    components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:tempDate];

    dayName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", weekDaySymbols[index++]];
    dayNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", components.day];

    components.day++;

    tempDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

It was very cool that DST is near and I found that bug before today submitting of the App.

Thanks to everyone. I guess it will help somebody in future.

Answer (score -4):

I think you should set the calendar for your NSDateFormatter object, try this:

```
[formatter setCalendar:calendar];
```

You should set the calendar before call `stringFromDate:` method.

Comment: I did tried everything: locale, calendar, timezone... I did try use NSDateFormatter and NSDataComponents, result the same.

Comment: @AntonAnisimov, how are you creating the calendar? Can you post the complete code?

Comment: I just found that when 27 of October it is a DST and if I have a 00:00 time, it become 23:00 due to DST. It doesn't matter to calendar itself. If I will use daytime for example 13:00 there will be no problem, but I found that NSDateComponents more fit to be aware that it works great. Thank you for help!